# I have installed and configured Zabbix agent in my Ubuntu 22.04 server but still zabbix availability shows unknown in Zabbix Monitoring Console

Tags: zabbix, ubuntu-22.04, server-monitoring

I have 2 local VMs which I am using as Zabbix Monitoring Server & Target Server as below -

`Zabbix Server IP = 192.168.122.91` (where the zabbix service is running)
`Target Server IP = 192.168.122.127` (which server I need to monitor)

I have Zabbix service installed, configured and running in Zabbix Server but when I want to monitor the Target Server from Zabbix Monitoring Console it shows me **Server Availability is Unknown**.

1. Using following method I have installed the Zabbix Agent in my Ubuntu 22.04 server (Target Server) -

```bash
cd /home/user1/
wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.0-4+ubuntu22.04_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i zabbix-release_6.0-4+ubuntu22.04_all.deb 
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install zabbix-agent
sudo systemctl start zabbix-agent
sudo systemctl enable zabbix-agent
```

2. To configure the Zabbix agent, I did the following steps -
   edit the file `sudo nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix-agentd.conf`

Then I have changed following values in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix-agentd.conf` file

From *ServerActive=127.0.0.1* to *ServerActive=192.168.10.91*
From *Hostname=Zabbix server* to *Hostname=Target server*

3. After that I have restarted the zabbix agent service -
   `sudo systemctl restart zabbix-agent`

After every steps done mentioned as above, the error arises in Zabbix Monitoring Console that **Server Availability = Unknown**

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: check agent log file in `/var/log`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago so I'll provide some insights:
Can you reach the servers from one another (a simple ping is enough) ? If so, check that the ports 10050 and 10051 are open on both servers and that they are allowed to connect to each other through them.

This problem is most likely due to the network or the firewall. Checking the logs is also a good idea as they'll show if the configured zabbix server is unreachable or not.